# SqlDataReader return empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

When I execute this code :

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM {0};";
query = string.Format(query, TEMP_TABLE_NAME);

var command = new SqlCommand(query, this.connection);
command.CommandTimeout = 0;

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        // Some stuff
    }
}
```

The reader is empty, the `reader.HasRows` is true, but on the first `reader.Read()`, it's over...

And when I execute this request in SQL Server Management Studio, it's OK, I get my records with all the columns and their values.

Do you please have an idea?

Comment: What's your query?

Comment: string query = @"SELECT * FROM {0};";

Comment: **DO NOT USE STRING.FORMAT FOR SQL DATA LIKE THAT!**. I suggest you do a quick Google search on Sql Injection. String.Format() and other concatenation methods leave you _extremely_ vulnerable.

Comment: Try commenting `command.CommandTimeout = 0;`

Comment: Unfortunaately same result with it @Chetan

Comment: What is the value of `TEMP_TABLE_NAME`? It could also be you are pointing to a different database all together.

Comment: ##Invoice the connection is on the right database

Comment: It works with SQL Adapter :
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from ##Invoice", connection);
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            var toto = dataset.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in toto.AsEnumerable()) // Loop over the rows.
            {
                // Stuff
            }

Comment: Global temp tables are just awful. They are fraught with concurrency issues when they are not handled correctly. They are often used when a normal temp table would be sufficient. Couple a global temp table with this absolutely frightening way of running queries and I would suggest that what you really need is to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: I tried the same code on my machine but it failed with error "Invalid object #MyTempTable". Not sure how are you even able to execute the command successfully.

Comment: Don't know for me it work swith adapter : show your code